# ASP.NET Razor split record and increase by one

Tags: sql, asp.net, razor

in my code I'm trying to display in a text box the record that follows the last one of my database. For example, if my last record is A560 I want to display A561. To achieve this I know I have to split the record and then manipulate it, but I haven't had any luck. Here is what the database looks like:

```
Point_ID    Project No.    Project Manager    Comments
A558        1304           Oscar Duran        Found destroyed
A559        1304           Oscar Duran        Helicopter access
A560        1356           Julio Bravo        Airport parking lot
```

This is my code so far:

```
@{  
Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";

var db = Database.Open("ControlPoints");                                                    
var SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM( SELECT TOP 5 * FROM AllControlMergedND WHERE Point_ID LIKE 'A___' ORDER BY Point_ID DESC )AS BaseData Order BY Point_ID ASC";                       
var SearchTerm = "";                                                                        

if(!Request.QueryString["SearchCP"].IsEmpty() ){                                            
    SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM AllControlMergedND WHERE Point_ID = @0";                 
    SearchTerm = Request.QueryString["SearchCP"];                                           
}

if(!Request.QueryString["SearchProject"].IsEmpty() ){                                       
    SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM AllControlMergedND WHERE [Project Used on] LIKE @0";
    SearchTerm = "%" + Request["SearchProject"] + "%";
}

var SelectData = db.Query(SelectCommand, SearchTerm);                                       
var grid = new WebGrid(source: SelectData, rowsPerPage: 10);                                
}

@{  
Validation.RequireField("Point_ID", " Required");                                           
Validation.RequireField("ProjectNo", " Required");                                          
Validation.RequireField("ProjectManager", " Required");

var Point_ID = "";                                                                          
var ProjectNo = "";                                                                         
var ProjectManager = "";

if(IsPost && Validation.IsValid() ){                                                        
    Point_ID = Request.Form["Point_ID"];
    ProjectNo = Request.Form["ProjectNo"];
    ProjectManager = Request.Form["ProjectManager"];
    db = Database.Open("ControlPoints");
    var InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO AllControlMergedND ([Point_ID], [Project No.], [Project Manager]) VALUES(@0, @1, @2)";
    db.Execute(InsertCommand, Point_ID, ProjectNo, ProjectManager);                                    

}


var SelectLastCP = "SELECT TOP 1 Point_ID FROM AllControlMergedND WHERE Point_ID LIKE 'A___' ORDER BY Point_ID DESC"; 
var SelectData2 = db.QuerySingle(SelectLastCP);                                             
var SuggestedPoint_ID = SelectData2.Point_ID;

}

<h2>Airborne Imaging Control Points Database</h2><br/><br/>                                 
    <form method="get">
        <fieldset>                                                                          
            <legend>Search Criteria</legend>                                                
            <div>
                <p><label for="SearchCP">Control Point ID:</label>                          
                <input type="text" name="SearchCP" value="@Request.QueryString["SearchCP"]" /> 
                <input type="submit" value="Search"/></p>                                   
            </div>
            <div>
                <p><label for="SearchProject">Project:</label>                              
                <input type="text" name="SearchProject" value="@Request.QueryString["SearchProject"]" />
                <input type="Submit" value="Search" /></p>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml(                                                                      
            tableStyle: "grid",                                                             
            headerStyle: "head",                                                            
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",                                                     
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("Point_ID"),
                grid.Column("Project No."),
                grid.Column("Project Used on"),
                grid.Column("WGS84 Lat"),
                grid.Column("WGS84 Long"),
                grid.Column("Ellips_Ht"),
                grid.Column("Project Manager"),
                grid.Column("Comments")
            )
        )
        <br/><br/>
    </div>

    <form method="post">                                                                    
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Create Control Point(s)</legend>
            <p><label for="Point_ID">Point ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Point_ID" value="@SuggestedPoint_ID" />
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Point_ID")</p>                                        

            <p><label for="ProjectNo">Project No:</label>
            <input type="text" name="ProjectNo" value="@Request.Form["ProjectNo"]" />
            @Html.ValidationMessage("ProjectNo")</p>                                        

            <p><label for="ProjectManager">Project Manager:</label>
            <input type="text" name="ProjectManager" value="@Request.Form["ProjectManager"]" />
            @Html.ValidationMessage("ProjectManager")</p>                                   

            <p><input type="submit" name="ButtonConfirm" value="Confirm" /></p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

As you can see, all I am able to do is to display the last record of my database in the text box, which in this case would be A560. The variable 'SuggestedPoint_ID' is holding that record. I have tried converting the data type, but had no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

What I need is to do the following. Split A560 in two parts 'A' and '560'. Then increment '560' by one to obtain '561' and finally attach 'A' again to '561' in order to obtain the next increment 'A561'.

Comment: what is the failure? did you get an exception?  how did you try and convert it?

Comment: Thanks for your help Phillip. The last error I got was "a namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods", but I think it is because I didn't account for the letter A.

Comment: Is it always the letter A or can it be other letters?

Comment: It is always the letter A

Comment: Wow, that stuff should be done in your controller...

Comment: I updated my answer below.  It takes the first character in the string and strips itself out of the string then converts to an integer and adds 1 to itself it successful.  finally combines into the result.

Comment: I am very new to this language and it's conventions, I don't know what is a controller, but I assume is a way of organizing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to convert "A560" to int for example then it won't work because you don't have a valid number.  A needs to be removed.

```
var SuggestedPoint_ID = SelectData2.Point_ID.Replace("A", "");
```

This is not my recommended way to do it as A could be anything such as AA or B or ZZZZ.  My point is that you need to describe what you need to get a better solution to your problem.

**UPDATE**

```
var source = "A560";
var lhs = source.Substring(0, 1);
var tmp = source.Replace(lhs, "");
int rhs;
if(int.TryParse(tmp, out rhs))
{
    rhs++;
}
var result = string.Format("{0}{1}", lhs, rhs);
```

Comment: Thank you Phillip, I just saw your answer and tried it. It worked very well!

Comment: Phillip, I was wondering if you could help me with the other question I posted a couple of days ago. It is related to the same project, please check it out, may be you know how to solve my problem. I appreciate your help.

Comment: One question, is the if statement necessary in the solution you posted?

Comment: int.tryparse returns true or false based on success.   that gives you a place to handle a failure.  you would not want to process any failures because you would be overwriting your good/valid data.